# Vuejs - Get dynamically generated input field and its value and change its color on change

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, vue-component, dynamic-programming, css-tables

In Vue.js I have created a table with editable fields.
The table fields are dynamically generated like:

```
   <b-table :items="filtered" :fields="columns">
      <template v-for="field in editableFields" v-slot:[tableCell(field.key)]="{ item }">
        <b-form-input  v-model="item[field.key]" v-bind:key="field.key""/>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

The v-slot method is this:

```
tableCell(fieldkey) {
  return `cell(${fieldkey})`;
}
```

That part is working juts fine :-)

My problem is that I would like to color a changed input field value and keep track of its value, so if its value changes back to the default, then the color defaults back to the original color. Like:

|_hello _|_default _|_input _|
|____|____|____|

|_hello _|_color _|_input _|
|______|_______|______|

So the value "default" is not colored, and when changed to "color" the input field chould be colored red.
When changing back to "default" the color should be reset.

The "`item[field.key]`" is representing each og the table cell values: "hello", "default", "input", "color" etc.

I've tried looking into "v-bind:class {active: active}" and v-on:change(item[field.key]) and Vues Watch, but I just can't find the way..

Thanks in regards

Comment: Can you explain why "v-bind:class {active: active}" didn't work? You should be able to do something like :class="{ active : originalValue !== newValue }"

Comment: Yes, sure. For example if the value is "hello" and I change it to "helloooo", then 'active = true', which is correct. If I change the value to "halloo", then 'active = false', which is wrong, because the value is still changed. 
And furthermore I don't know how to bind a styling class to the object if active is true or false.

Comment: That's what :class="{ active : active }" does, it puts a styling class called "active" when the Vue js property "active" is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a quick demo, showing how to apply a css class when the value is different.

I hope this helps.

```css
.changed {
   background-color: orange;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<input type="text" :class="{ changed : oldValue !== newValue }" v-model="newValue" />
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      oldValue: "Hello",
      newValue: "Hello"
    }
  }
})
</script>
```